# Why aren't the cells in my UICollectionView updating their size when I update the flow layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I have a grid of cells in a UICollectionViewController:

[Pretty standard 3 column grid (based on approximate cell size, wider layouts have more cells)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY7KD.png)

The overall idea of the app is that a user taps a cell which counts down the specified time, and once the timer is complete it will unlock the next time. The first time is always unlocked:

[After the first 3 buttons are tapped and have counted down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWxnh.png)

Tapping the same cell twice in succession removes all cells except the first and the one which was tapped twice, to allow the user to loop around.
Doing this should also update the collectionViewLayout to be only 2 columns of equal width which fill the screen, but at the moment the first and second cells are not resizing:

[After a button is tapped twice in succession](http:// i.imgur.com/cLvaApG.png)

The layout is definitely updated / invalidated because rotating the device updates the cells as expected:

[Rotated to landscape mode](http:// i.imgur.com/rngwzre.png)

[And rotated back to portrait](http:// i.imgur.com/ajwPr1J.png)

I'm sizing the cells as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if repeating {
        let target = collectionView.frame.width
        let targetFraction = target / 2
        return CGSize(width: targetFraction, height: targetFraction)
    }

    let target = CGFloat(125)
    let frameRef = collectionView.frame.width
    let frameWidthRemainder = frameRef % target
    let frameWidthRounded = frameRef - frameWidthRemainder
    let columnCount = frameWidthRounded / target
    let columnWidth = frameRef / columnCount
    return CGSize(width: columnWidth, height: columnWidth)
}
```

`Repeating` is a bool which is set / reset by tapping on the cells as part of an action:

```
@IBAction func circleProgressButtonTapped(sender: CircleProgressButton) {
    ...
    if previouslySelectedButton == sender && !repeating {
        repeating = true
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        buttons = [buttons[0], buttons[row]]
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        for button in buttons {
            button.circleProgressButton.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When the device rotates, I'm resetting the layout with:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    for button in buttons {
        button.circleProgressButton.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

`Buttons` is an array of the cells, which is populated / reset with:

```
func refreshView() {
    if let min = defaults.valueForKey(userDefaultsKeys.min.rawValue) as? Int {
        self.min = min
    }

    if let max = defaults.valueForKey(userDefaultsKeys.max.rawValue) as? Int {
        self.max = max
    }

    buttons = []

    collectionView?.reloadData()

    for i in 0..<buttonCount {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { break }
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
        let multiplier = i + 1
        let time = min * multiplier
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CircleProgressButtonCollectionViewCell
        cell.circleProgressButton.delegate = self
        cell.circleProgressButton.value = time
        cell.circleProgressButton.resetText()
        cell.circleProgressButton.indexPath = indexPath
        cell.circleProgressButton.progress = 0
        cell.circleProgressButton.activeProgressColour = theme
        cell.circleProgressButton.tintColor = theme
        cell.circleProgressButton.setNeedsDisplay()
        if i > 0 {
            cell.circleProgressButton.enabled = false
        }
        buttons.append(cell)
    }
}
```

I know this is probably not the best way to be making the cells, but any other way caused problems with the cell re-use. I.e. the progress in a cell would also be re-used.

I'm not even sure if the issue is `collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` is not invalidating properly or what. It could just be the collectionView needs to be updated in some other way. I don't even know if it's the collectionView or the cell I should be focusing on. It's just weird that the first two cells are the only ones not updating, especially as I'm not doing anything different to them.

I would list everything I've tried but I'd be here a while. Among other things, I've tried:

```
    if previouslySelectedButton == sender && !repeating {
        ...
        collectionViewLayout.prepareLayout()
        if let collectionView = collectionView {
            collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
            collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
        if let collectionViewLayoutCollectionView = collectionViewLayout.collectionView {
            collectionViewLayoutCollectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
            collectionViewLayoutCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
        collectionView?.setNeedsDisplay()
        collectionViewLayout.collectionView?.setNeedsDisplay()
        collectionView?.setNeedsLayout()
        collectionViewLayout.collectionView?.setNeedsLayout()
        collectionView?.reloadData()

        buttons = [buttons[0], buttons[row]]

        for button in buttons {
            button.setNeedsLayout()
            button.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
```

I've tried setting the `buttons` array to empty, reloading, then populating it (generating entirely new cells) and reloading it again but even that doesn't work.

If I have to radically alter my entire approach, so be it.

Comment: not able to open a link u mention for check images

Comment: @Anny I can't post images or more than 2 urls due to lack of reputation. The first 2 links work fine, for the others take out the space in between http:// and the rest of the link.